# TypeScript assert function

Tags: typescript

I want to create an assert function with TypeScript which will tell me if an element is an instance of, for example, an HTMLElement.

I'm trying to build it like this:

```
function assertIntanceOf(
  element: unknown,
  prototype: ??? // which type should I place here?
): boolean {
  return element instanceof prototype;
}
```

and it must work like this:

```
const elem = document.querySelector('.someClass'); // returns an elem
assertInstanceOf(elem, HTMLElement); // returns true

const elem2 = document.querySelector('.someClassWhichNotExists'); // returns null cause elem with class .someClassWhichNotExists doesn't exist
assertInstanceOf(elem, HTMLElement); // returns false


const someVar = 123; // simply a number
assertInstanceOf(someVar, HTMLElement); //returns false

const someObj = { //just an object
 a: 'abc'
} 
assertInstanceOf(someVar, HTMLElement); //returns false
```

Which type should I place for `prototype` argument?

Comment: Why not just use the `typeof` operator itself?

Comment: @VLAZ `typeof elem`  in this case will return an object simply. It's not really compatible to TypeScript

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `instanceof` operator. I'm not sure why I said `typeof`.

Comment: Why not simply `instanceof` then? It seems to me you are trying to rewrite `instanceof`? For that matter, all your custom function does is `return a instanceof b`

Comment: @VLAZ I can use `typeof` but I'm interested in the type of argument here, as I've asked. I want to practice this case and find out how to create a function properly

Comment: @JeremyThille cause it's a study task and I wanna to complete it like that if it possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make this [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), using the `new()` "construct signature" per [the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-write-typeof-t-new-t-or-instanceof-t-in-my-generic-function), and return a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) so that using it will actually narrow the type of the first argument:

```js
function assertInstanceOf<T>(
  element: unknown,
  prototype: { new(): T },
): element is T {
  // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoEkypTKQYDywAPACoB8AFAFCKIYA2GAthmFAFyLgA1mDgB3MABomiAA5Y4UBQE8ZGfgG9EYDKLoBKflUQBfKQZbsuPRDFSIj66VgxQQWJG07coNgkRJwwLLyilAqGADcDMYMDBCsaHYAYnBwiI7MzACOIMgQgvrp0pmZzq7uiABEOXmClcUm0bHsPsCp-EIi4ogAvFo6iClw+lEMMEF0idh4fsQQZMB0bXASg6l6ekUlywB0Nfn6TUA)

That said, TypeScript already knows about [`instanceof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards), so you don't necessarily need to put this in a function.